# 'Additional Charge Disclosure' failure for Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

Reason for rejection: Offer descriptions must notify users in the description of any extra charges to use advertised features or to activate additional features or content. Please update the description of the offer to include such information and re-submit your offer.

Should I include any extra additional information or documents regarding the charge disclosures for mu add-in or just text information is enough?

Answer (score -1):

If there are any charges for a user at any point to use the add-in, this must be disclosed in the description.

Comment: Thank you. However, there is no additional cost for a user to avail the plug-in. The Paperflite account they procure includes this feature. This was documented in the descripton section, with a specific call out for  "Requirements:
A registered Paperflite account which can be availed at www.paperflite.com
Outlook, Outlook for Mac, or Outlook on the web".  Not sure what additional information to include here, please.

Answer (score -1):

If no payment is required at any point to use an add-in such as at the end of a free trial, for additional functionality etc. You can make this clear in the certification notes of a submission.

Comment: If you have to add information to an existing answer, please edit that answer and don't start a new one. Also note that "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic"